# Tool RESHAPE in QGIS version 2.18 x 3.4

Tags: qgis

In version 2.18, when using the Reshape tool on multilines and polygons in 3D, the Z coordinate of new points are interpolated based on Z coordinates of existing points. For example, a line with "z" : 100,150 if I reshape Z stay : 100,115,130,135,150.

Now in QGIS version 3.4 all new points I create with the Reshape tool have z=0. Last example stays : 100, 55, 0, 75, 150, because in the New point z=0.

Is there an equivalent to the old Reshape tool in QGIS 3?